# How do I manually assign the location of bars along the x-axis using barplot()?

Tags: r

I have a list of means.

```
means=c(anc3mean,l3mean,anc5mean,l5mean,anczmean,z12mean);means
[1] 0.07025897 0.42328670 0.05697524 0.53915431 0.01893219 0.10878638
```

I have created a barplot from those means.

```
bars=barplot(means,ylim=c(0,.8))
```

[image]

I would like to have the "bars" be centered at the values 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8 along the x axis.

I have tried the following:

```
bars=barplot(means,ylim=c(0,.8),at=c(1,2,4,5,7,8))
```

This does not work however because "at" is not an argument for "barplot()".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could insert "empty" elements

```
# x position of the means
loc <- c(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8)

# Fill with empty elements
hght <- setNames(rep(0, max(loc)), 1:max(loc))
hght[loc] <- means

# Plot
x = barplot(hght, ylim = c(0, 0.8))
axis(1, at = x, labels = names(hght))
```

[image]

If you don't want the x-axis, simply remove the `axis(...)` line.

---

### Sample data

```
means <- c(0.07025897, 0.42328670, 0.05697524, 0.53915431, 0.01893219, 0.10878638)
```